# Como pasar el Id en un onkeyup

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, modal, onkeyup

Estoy tratando de copiar una cantidad ingresada de una caja de texto a otra, el proceso es que se habrá un modal donde esta una tabla que se crea a partir de otra y uso un onkeyup para copiar la información ingresada a la otra tabla.

Este es el codigo que uso para crear la tabla en el modal, en el onkeyup envio como parametro this para que tome el Id, el cual si funciona.

```
  function CreateTable() {
    productsArray = AddMemories();
    if (productsArray == 0) {
        return swal({
            title: "ATENCIÓN",
            text: "No se ha seleccionado ninguna memoria descriptiva",
            type: "error",
            confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        });
    }
    let myTable = "<table class='table table-striped' id='tabla1'>";
    myTable += "<th>Folio</th>";
    myTable += "<th>Expediente</th>";
    myTable += "<th>Siniestro</th>";
    myTable += "<th>Poliza</th>";
    myTable += "<th>Aseguradora</th>";
    myTable += "<th>MEXICO ASISTENCIA SA DE CV</th>";
    myTable += "<th>Total</th>"
    myTable += "<th>Total facturado</th>"
    myTable += "<th>Borrar</th>"
    for (let i = 0; i < productsArray.length; i++) {
        myTable += "<tr>";
        myTable += "<td>" + productsArray[i].fol + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + productsArray[i].exp + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + productsArray[i].sin + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + productsArray[i].pol + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + productsArray[i].cli + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + productsArray[i].mex + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + productsArray[i].tot + "</td>";
        //en esta sección hago en envio del Id
        myTable += "<td> <input id='"+productsArray[i].id+"' type='text' onkeyup='copyCollection(this)'></td>"
        myTable += " <td><button type='button' id='ch" + productsArray[i].cot + "' class='btn btn-danger borrar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button></td>";
        myTable += "</tr>";

    }
    myTable += "</table>";
    document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = myTable;
    $("#myModal").modal();
}
```

Este es el método copyCollection

```
function copyCollection(b) {
    var sd = b.id;
    alert("e_" + sd);
    document.getElementById("bp_" + b.id).value = document.getElementById(b.id).value   
}
```

y este es el mensaje que muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces es mi duda, como castear esa variable para que no salga ese espacio para que pueda enviar los valores ingresados a la otra tabla

Answer (score 0):

El event handler onkeyup recibe un objeto del tipo [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) el cual hereda de [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) y éste último tiene una propiedad que te servirá: target. Con esto en mente, puedes obtener el id de ese objeto. Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
// Se pasa el objeto del tipo KeyEvent que contiene la propiedad target
myTable += "<td> <input id='"+productsArray[i].id+"' type='text' onkeyup='copyCollection(event)'></td>"
```

Y en la función copyCollection:

```
 function copyCollection(b) {
    // b contiene target y ese a su vez contiene id
    var sd = b.target.id;
    alert("e_" + sd);
    document.getElementById("bp_" + b.target.id).value = document.getElementById(b.target.id).value   
}
```

Comment: Aun me sigue dejando el espacio entre la "e_" y el id del input, lo que yo quiero es eliminar ese espacio que es lo evita que pueda copiar el valor ingresado a otro

Comment: quisiera que me lo muestre de esta manera "e_3568" que es el Id del input

Comment: Se me pasó un b.id y lo cambié por b.target.id. Si sólo copiaste y pegaste, vuelve a probar a ver si funciona.